# iOS Swift: Custom interactive transition

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimationtransition

I wrote a custom swipe transition that works fine on a modal presentation. But in a push presentation the "to" view position is not animating.

I've tried the same code with switching the translation with alpha and it works.

The from view works perfectly, it's just the to view that stays fixed during the animation.

```
func transitionAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating {
    let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
    let container = transitionContext.containerView

    let toController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
    toController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)

    guard
    let to = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to),
    let from = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)
        else {
        print("To or from view are nil!")
        fatalError()
    }

    container.addSubview(to)

    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, curve: .linear)
    var toStartingPoint: CGPoint
    var fromEndingPoint: CGPoint

    switch self.from {
    case .down:
        toStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -from.bounds.height)
        fromEndingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: from.bounds.height)
    case .top:
        toStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: from.bounds.height)
        fromEndingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -from.bounds.height)
    case .right:
        toStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: from.bounds.width, y: 0)
        fromEndingPoint = CGPoint(x: -from.bounds.width, y: 0)
    case .left:
        toStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: -from.bounds.width, y: 0)
        fromEndingPoint = CGPoint(x: from.bounds.width, y: 0)
    }

    to.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: toStartingPoint.x, y: toStartingPoint.y)

    animator.addAnimations({
        from.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: fromEndingPoint.x, y: fromEndingPoint.y)
    }, delayFactor: 0.0)

    animator.addAnimations({
        to.transform = .identity
    }, delayFactor: 0.0)


    animator.addCompletion { [weak self] position in
        switch position {
        case .start:
            self?.auxCancelCompletion?()
            transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
            self?.auxAnimationsCancel?()
        case .end:
            self?.auxEndCompletion?()
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            from.transform = .identity
            to.transform = .identity
        default:
            transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
            self?.auxAnimationsCancel?()
        }
    }

    if let auxAnimations = auxAnimations {
        animator.addAnimations(auxAnimations)
    }

    self.animator = animator
    self.context = transitionContext

    animator.addCompletion { [unowned self] _ in
        self.animator = nil
        self.context = nil
    }
    animator.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return animator
}
```

I was thinking that was a problem about delegates but the navigationDelgate is correctly set, otherwise I think I wouldn't see any animation..

Delegate setting:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    transitionHelper = SwipeInteractiveTransitionHelper(withDelegate: self)
}


extension TodayViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return transitionHelper?.swipeTransition
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerFor animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return transitionHelper?.swipeTransition
    }
}
```

and here is the custom push coordinator, where the viewController is the next view controller, and where I attach the delegate.

```
    case .pushCustom:
        guard let navigationController = currentViewController.navigationController else {
            fatalError("Can't push a view controller without a current navigation controller")
        }
        guard let current = currentViewController as? UINavigationControllerDelegate else {
            fatalError("Can't push a view controller without a current  navigation delegate")
        }
        navigationController.delegate = current
        navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true) { [weak self] in
            self?.currentViewController = SceneCoordinator.actualViewController(for: viewController)
            completion?()
        }
```

Comment: did u try https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero this or not?

Comment: I don't want to use dependencies when I could do on my own

Comment: I understand why waste your time when they have given you enough controls to work with which is perfect.

Comment: to make practice, to become better

Comment: Ok then @Miotz, you can take the reference from there as they have already implemented navigation controller custom transition

Comment: @HarjotSingh I'm asked why my animator works fine except for the translation of the to view controller, I've already tried to look into here but can't find the proper reference

Comment: How did you setting the delegate object. I tried and find it is working fine.

Comment: did you tried with a push? I'm going to update the question with the codes you are asking

Comment: @E.Coms updated

Comment: Where is the pushed view controller coming from? Is that from storyboard initializing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved animating a snapshot of the destination view, instead of directly animating the destination view.

let to = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)
let toViewSnapshot = to.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)

Just use the toViewSnapshot for the animation

Comment: The animator is fine, Just the way to call it. I updated my answer too.  Any way, It's great to hear you solved.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is this way. Hope it will help you.

```
VC:UIViewController
{
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any){
navigationController?.delegate = self
let destine = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "target")
navigationController?.pushViewController(destine!, animated: true)
}

  func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?{
    return Traistion()
}

}


 class Traistion:  NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning{


func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let animator  = transitionAnimator(using: transitionContext)
    animator.startAnimation()
}

var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator!
var context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning!

func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval{
    return 1.0
}

enum Direction {
    case down
    case top
    case left
    case right
}

var from : Direction = .left

var auxCancelCompletion :(()->())? = {
    return nil
}()

var auxAnimationsCancel :(()->())? = {
    return nil
}()

var auxEndCompletion :(()->())? = {
    return nil
}()


var auxAnimations : (()->())?
func transitionAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating {
    let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
    let container = transitionContext.containerView

    let toController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
    toController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)

    guard
        let to = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to),
        let from = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)
        else {
            print("To or from view are nil!")
            fatalError()
    }

    container.addSubview(to)

    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, curve: .linear)
    var toStartingPoint: CGPoint
    var fromEndingPoint: CGPoint

    switch self.from {
    case .down:
        toStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -from.bounds.height)
        fromEndingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: from.bounds.height)
    case .top:
        toStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: from.bounds.height)
        fromEndingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -from.bounds.height)
    case .right:
        toStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: from.bounds.width, y: 0)
        fromEndingPoint = CGPoint(x: -from.bounds.width, y: 0)
    case .left:
        toStartingPoint = CGPoint(x: -from.bounds.width, y: 0)
        fromEndingPoint = CGPoint(x: from.bounds.width, y: 0)
    }

    to.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: toStartingPoint.x, y: toStartingPoint.y)

    animator.addAnimations({
        from.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: fromEndingPoint.x, y: fromEndingPoint.y)
    }, delayFactor: 0.0)

    animator.addAnimations({
        to.transform = .identity
    }, delayFactor: 0.0)


    animator.addCompletion { [weak self] position in
        switch position {
        case .start:
            self?.auxCancelCompletion?()
            transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
            self?.auxAnimationsCancel?()
        case .end:
            self?.auxEndCompletion?()
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            from.transform = .identity
            to.transform = .identity
        default:
            transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
            self?.auxAnimationsCancel?()
        }
    }

    if let auxAnimations = auxAnimations {
        animator.addAnimations(auxAnimations)
    }

    self.animator = animator
    self.context = transitionContext

    animator.addCompletion { [unowned self] _ in
       //self.animator = nil
       // self.context = nil
    }
    animator.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return animator
   }

 }
```

When use `interruptibleAnimator`. It will call this function at least twice and you are supposed to provide the same animator but different one.  So you have to call it like this way:

```
  func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

 animator =    transitionAnimator(using: transitionContext) as! UIViewPropertyAnimator
 animator.startAnimation()
}
func interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating {
    return  animator
}

var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator!
var context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning!
```

or simpler like this:

```
 func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
}
func interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating {
    if    animator == nil {animator =    transitionAnimator(using: transitionContext) as! UIViewPropertyAnimator
        animator.startAnimation()}
    return  animator
}
```

Here `animator` will be called twice and which is the same one. If

```
 func interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating { 
   return transitionAnimator(using: transitionContext) }
```

This is not the right way to use as the animator will be different.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning/1829434-interruptibleanimator

See the last line in the document.

Comment: but if you implement the func interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating {
  return transitionAnimator(using: transitionContext)
 }

the transition does not work properly

Comment: solved using; let toViewSnapshot = to.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true),